# QoQ growth SQL in GCP Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, lag

I am trying to build bigquery SQL to calculate the QoQ growth for a table in monthly grain.Growth is defined as difference between last month of previous quarter and  last month of current quarter. Source dataset would be :
[image]

and target dataset would be :
[image]

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: So what have you tried and what specific issue are you having? As this is not a free coding site, you need to show at least some effort to solve the problem yourself

Comment: Also, don’t use images. All information should be provided as editable text - then someone can copy it if they want to try out a solution